# Show that $||f||_{\infty} = \min \{M \ | \ m\{x \in [a,b] \ | |f(x)| > M\} =0 \}$ for $f$ in $L^{\infty}[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For $f$ in $L^{\infty}[a,b],$ show that
$$||f||_{\infty} = \min \{M  \ | \ m\{x \in [a,b] \ | |f(x)| > M\} =0 \}$$ and if, furthermore, f is continuous on $ [a,b]$ that $$||f||_{\infty} = ||f||_{max}$$

**Here is what I started with:**
We define $L^{\infty}[a,b]$ to be collection of equivalence classes $[f]$ for which $f$ is essentially bounded.

A function $f$ is essentially bounded provided there is some $M >0$ called essential upper bound for $f$ for which $|f(x)| \leq M $ for almost all $x \in [a,b]$

We also define $||f||_{\infty}$ to be the infimum of the essential upper bounded for $f$. $||f||_{\infty}$ also called essential supremum

Comment: So all you've done is write down the definitions? Have you noticed that the first thing you are to prove *is* the definition of $\|f\|_\infty$, expressed in symbols instead of words?

Comment: I see now, what about the second part? any hint or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M = \|f\|_\infty$, then $\mu(\{|f| >M\}) = 0$ Therefore this set cannot contain $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$ for any $x\in[a, b]$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Now, recall that $f$ is continuous.